# Python Dictionary:removing a string from a tuple( WHICH is a key .)

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a dictionary like

```
dic ={('L', 'N', 'C'):6, ('N', 'L', 'C'):4, ('C', 'N', 'L'):3})
```

I want to remove the string 'C' from all keys.
Is there any efficient way of doing so

Comment: Questioàn strangely similar to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571438/remove-a-value-from-a-dictionary-with-multiple-values

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with a single [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> dic ={('L', 'N', 'C'):6, ('N', 'L', 'C'):4, ('C', 'N', 'L'):3}
>>> {tuple(l for l in k if l != 'C'):v for k,v in dic.items()}
{('L', 'N'): 6, ('N', 'L'): 4}
```

Note that the removal of `'C'` makes `('N', 'L', 'C')` and `('C', 'N', 'L')` clash as they both become `('N', 'L')`. It is not clear from the question how you wish to handle that.

Comment: ...and the code in your answer "handles" it by just keeping the value of the last one seen.

Comment: This code creates a new dictionary (that is to say with a new id). Even for the keys that don't contain 'C', the execution of `tuple(l for l in k if l != 'C')` is performed, creating new keys with new ids even if they have the same value. If the dictionary is big, all that represents useless work. - By the way, if the ancient dictionary isn't destroyed, it remains.

Comment: This seems to give tuples but the order of the tuples are all different then the original tuple. Can you explain why please?

Comment: @user1828603: If you mean that the keys are ordered differently in the final dictionary than they are in the original one, this is because `dict` does not guarantee any particular ordering of its keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,v in dic.iteritems():
    if 'C' in k:
        dic[tuple(el for el in k if el!='C')] = dic.pop(k)
```

In this solution,
only the keys that contain the element to eliminate are changed (new objects since tuples are immutable).
The dictionary is modified in place
and the values remain the same objects.

The following code shows that.

```
dico = {(1,2,8):'aa',  
        (25,8,45,9):'gerard',
        (268,54,0):'marine',
        (81,3,8,7):'emma',
        (7,9,6):'louis'}

print '  id(dico) : ',id(dico)
for k,v in dico.iteritems():
    print id(k),'%-25s' % repr(k),id(v),v

idk = [id(el) for el in dico]

for k,v in dico.iteritems():
    if 8 in k:
        dico[tuple(el for el in k if el!=8)] = dico.pop(k)

print
print '  id(dico) : ',id(dico)
for k,v in dico.iteritems():
    print '%d %-30s %d %s' %\
          (id(k), ('[new id] ' if id(k) not in idk else '         ')+repr(k),id(v),v)
```

result

```
  id(dico) :  18737456
18751976 (268, 54, 0)              18718464 marine
11258576 (1, 2, 8)                 18566968 aa
18539072 (25, 8, 45, 9)            18603776 gerard
18606768 (81, 3, 8, 7)             18718432 emma
18752056 (7, 9, 6)                 18718592 louis

  id(dico) :  18737456
18752216 [new id] (1, 2)                18566968 aa
18751976          (268, 54, 0)          18718464 marine
18752176 [new id] (81, 3, 7)            18718432 emma
18752056          (7, 9, 6)             18718592 louis
18752416 [new id] (25, 45, 9)           18603776 gerard
```